# How to set a timestamp when value of a cell containing a formula updates the first time?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, timestamp, worksheet

I have a workbook with three worksheets.

Worksheet1 has rolls ups of worksheet2 and worksheet3. Worksheet1 is never manually updated because the data/information is updated in worksheet2/3 and it populates into worksheet1 through a vlookup formula in the cells.

I want a timestamp for whenever the cells in column D in worksheet1 first contains a percent of 1%-99%.

- I want this timestamp to never change after the first data is entered.
- I also want the timestamp to display in column G.

I want another timestamp for whenever the cells in column D in worksheet1 first contains 100%.

- I want this timestamp to never change after the first data is entered.
- I also want the timestamp to print in column H.

This only picks up when the cells are changed manually. Since the worksheet populates from formulas it didn't catch the change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange As Range
Dim myDateTimeRage As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

Set myTableRange = Range("D1:D314")

If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set myDateTimeRage = Range("N" & Target.Row)
Set myUpdatedRange = Range("O" & Target.Row)

If myDateTimeRage.Value = "" Then
    myDateTimeRage.Value = Now
End If

myUpdatedRange.Value = Now

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're dealing with formulas, you need to use `Worksheet_Calculate`, not `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: you would have to look for changes in the workshhets 2+3; if they change look into worksheet 1 if the cells contain what you llok for, and then set the timestamp.

Comment: if i use worksheet_calculate the code does not work

Comment: Are you trying to put a timestamp in `columns G and H` per your text, or `Columns N and O` per your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic code that works with `Worksheet_Calculate`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim myTableRange As Range

Set myTableRange = Range("D1:D30") 'Change the range as needed

    For Each cel In myTableRange 
    'when a cell is changed in the range due to a formula, the code loops through and checks all the cells for a change. 

        If cel.Value >= 0.01 And cel.Value <= 0.99 And cel.Offset(, 3).Value = "" And cel.Offset(, 4).Value = "" Then 
       'If the timestamp is not for columns G and H, change the offset(,3) to 10, and offset(,4) to 11

            cel.Offset(, 3).Value = Now

        ElseIf cel.Value = 1# And cel.Offset(, 4).Value = "" Then
        'Test for 100%

            cel.Offset(, 4).Value = Now
        End If

    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: This code worked great! I want to add a statement that checks for existing data first in the G and H column. If there is existing dates there from a previous day the code was ran and timestamped, i don't want this code above to run and override those existing dates. Is it possible to nest this code into another else if statement?